# WooCommerce Bookings: Set date picker to a specific date programmatically via JQuery

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I want to know if there's a way to automatically set the start date an end date of a bookable product using Woocommerce bookings. What I want to achieve is when a user goes to my product page the start date and end date (month, day and year) will be set depending on what I want it to be via Jquery. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do like that
`jQuery.datepicker._selectDate("DatePickerID","2019-11-13")`

to select run 1 time to select Strat date and again to select end date
`DatePickerId` reference to calendar date picker.